# How to use Ionic Cloud with Ionic 2, Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

The docs is very unclear. I want to know where should I put the code:

```
 this.deploy.check().then((snapshotAvailable: boolean) => {
    this.deploy.download().then(() => {
        return this.deploy.extract().then( () => {
         this.deploy.load();
         console.log('Extract Succesful');
     };
  });
 });
```

So I want just like the old behavior on Ionic 1. I can put the code in app.ts and it watches everything (all the pages and all the providers) and detect if any changes and do an auto update on client devices. But the doc said I need to inject import {Deploy} from '@ionic/cloud-angular' in EACH PAGE? This really confuses me. How can I just put 1 code in 1 place and watch over everything. A kinda set it and forget about it solution like Ionic 1...

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something across the app, usually you add it to the `app.ts` files constructor.

have a look at the [ionic-cloud-angular](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cloud-angular) library, it has a code example on how to use it inside `app.ts` file

Answer (score 0):

http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-push-notifications/

go through this video tutorial . it's good for beginners

complete documentation will be available in this link http://docs.ionic.io/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code in app.component.ts after

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
  ...
  this.watchDeploy();
}
```

Than you can add the function:

```
watchDeploy(){
// check for update once then with a delay
  this.checkNewVersion().then(()=> {
  setTimeout(()=>this.watchDeploy(), 20 * 1000);
})

checkNewVersion():Promise<any> {
 return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject)=> {
  return this.deploy.check().then((snapshotAvailable: boolean) => {
   if (snapshotAvailable) {
    return this.deploy.download().then(() => {
      return this.deploy.extract().then( () => {
       this.deploy.load();
       console.log('Extract Succesful');
       resolve();
      };
    });
   } else {
       resolve();
   }
  })
 })
}
```

You just need to inject "import {Deploy} from '@ionic/cloud-angular'" in the page where you use it. Here it would be in app.component.ts only.
Best Practice would be to create a new service for this.